# How to set options for console command

Tags: symfony

My console command has two options (not arguments).

This is my command codes

```
class crawlerCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
        ->setName('top:crawler')
        ->setDescription('Greet someone')
        ->addOption('opt1', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'option1')
        ->addOption('opt2',null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'option2');
```

then I am trying to call command from the Controller

for example I want to do this console command from the Controller

```
$ app/console top:crawler --opt1=s --opt2=2
```

therefore I made this code.

```
public function indexAction(){

    $command = $this->get('crawlerCommandService');

    $inputDefinition = new InputDefinition(array(
            new InputOption('opt1', 's', InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL),
            new InputOption('opt2', '2', InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL),
    ));
    $input = new ArgvInput(array('argv' => 'app'));
    $input->bind($inputDefinition);
    $output = new ConsoleOutput();
    $returnCode = $command->run($input, $output);
```

However it does not work.

Please give some hint.

---

I can solve the problem using ArrayInput instead of ArgvInput.

I write down the code here.

```
    $command = $this->get('crawlerCommandService');

    $output = new ConsoleOutput();
    $arguments = array(
        '--opt1' => 's',
        '--opt2' => '2'
    );
    $input = new ArrayInput($arguments);
    $returnCode = $command->run($input, $output);
```

Comment: What would be the benefit of calling the command? Surely if you wanted to repeat logic then you would have all of that in a service which you can then call separately. A command is just another view as far as I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first element of the array passed in the constructor is the name of the running application as explained in the [documentation](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php)

And looking at the code, you can pass anything as the first element if you are manually constructing it.

```
$input = new ArgvInput(array(
    'app' => 'something', 'arg1' => 'val1', 'arg2' => 'val2'
));
```

Comment: Thanks I understand your explaination,the first element doesnt have meaning.However my command doesnt have arguments, but options.I would like to know how to pass the option values to command.

Comment: Try one of these. `new ArgvInput(array('app', '-opt1=val1', 'opt2=val2'))` or `new ArgvInput(array('app' => 'something', '-opt1' => 'val1', '-opt2' => 'val2'))`